# Misunderstood the numbers reported by block_dump as block number

Tags: linux

I tried to track disc activity with echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/block_dump
and misunderstood the numbers reported by block_dump as block number

what i have:

> python2.5(30207): READ block 301989912 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30207): READ block 301989976 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30206): READ block 301989944 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30206): READ block 301989928 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30205): READ block 301989904 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30206): READ block 17735536 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30206): READ block 17735544 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30206): READ block 22190248 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30206): READ block 22190264 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30206): READ block 22190256 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30206): READ block 22190272 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30205): READ block 13893648 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30207): READ block 13893728 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30207): READ block 13893720 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30207): READ block 13893696 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30207): READ block 13893736 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30207): READ block 13893672 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30207): READ block 13893664 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30205): READ block 13893688 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30207): READ block 13893680 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30207): READ block 13893656 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30207): READ block 13893704 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30208): READ block 13893712 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30205): READ block 17989712 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30208): READ block 17989720 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30208): READ block 22190816 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30208): READ block 22190832 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30208): READ block 22190824 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30205): READ block 294649912 on sdc1
>
> python2.5(30205): READ block 294649920 on sdc1

if i try debugfs icheck for 13893712, 17989720 its ok but what is high numbers 294649920 and 301989904?

tune2fs -l /dev/sdc1

> Inode count:              19546112
>
> Block count:              39072080
>
> Reserved block count:     1953604
>
> Free blocks:              36601582
>
> Free inodes:              19440532

Answer (score 1):

it is sector number in kernel log. one sector is 512 bytes. fs blocks are 4096 bytes usually.